# How to parallely iterate a collection in java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Is it possible to iterate a Collection parallel in Java. I'm looking for something like c# `Parallel.ForEach` in `System.Threading.Tasks`-Namespace

Comment: Java8: `collection.stream().parallel().forEach(...)`

Answer (score 2):

The `Stream` API in `Java 1.8` was designed with `parallelism` in mind, so you can convert any `Stream` to a parallel stream. for example:

```
 Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
```

And In fact every `Stream` can be converted into a parallel one

```
Stream<Integer> parallel = stream.parallel();
```

And `Collection` provides a method that return a `parallelStream`.

```
Stream<Integer> parallel = Arrays.asList(1,2,3).parallelStream();
```

Now, this does not mean every operation can be efficiently parallelised, it depends on the nature of the source collection and the task you doing. 
[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170832/java-8s-streams-why-parallel-stream-is-slower)

Comment: Indeed. Be very careful about using `parallel()`, it has a lot of caveats and shouldn't be used without fully understanding what it does.

Comment: @Sleiman: I'm using Java 1.7 Any other way to achieve it in Java 1.7

Comment: @VinothSankar probably RxJava is the best, but your code wouldn't be concise

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Java 8, you should use [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). If you're not on Java 8, there's no baked-in equivalent.

```
sandwichCollection.parallelStream().forEach((sandwich) -> {
    sandwich.eat();
});
```