# Is there any better way I can write using Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
    public List<ArrayList<String>> removeRow(int columnIndex,Set<String> masterData,List<ArrayList<String>> rowColumnData){ 

        List<ArrayList<String>> finalData= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        for(ArrayList<String> data: rowColumnData){
            String columnVal=data.get(columnIndex);
            if(masterData.contains(columnVal){
            finalData.add(data);
        }

        return finalData;
    }
```

I need to filter out rows if a specific set of values of a column didn't match.
My masterData contains 30,000 records.
My rowColumnData will going to hold 2M records, basically a row whose column values are store in a array list and the entire table data is List>.

How can using stream API write the code which is going to give me better performance?

Comment: @Samuel Added the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good at performance level while using streams but you can do this by using `parallelStream` where multiple thread get process the data,
need to know some interesting facts [Java 8's streams: why parallel stream is slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170832/java-8s-streams-why-parallel-stream-is-slower)

```
List<List<String>> result = rowColumnData
                            .parallelStream()
                            .filter(l->masterData.contains(l.get(columnIndex)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But be aware

**List E get(int index) Throws :**

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

**Set boolean contains(Object o) Throws :**

> NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this set does not permit null elements (optional)

Comment: Can you explain how would parallel streams used in the current case help "improve the performance"?