# Comparison between sequential and parallel stream

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, java-8, parallel-processing, parallelstream

Should I keep using parallel stream here or should I go with sequential stream. I have tested it on various environments. In my local it was considerably fast but in the test environment, it was slower. doc is a list of strings of size 30K appx. Please suggest.

```
doc.parallelStream().filter(transaction -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(transaction))
                .forEach(transaction -> sendTransactionsToTopic(transaction, isEncryptionEnabled))
```

Comment: And what `sendTransactionsToTopic()` does?

Comment: Did you test with ~30K strings on local and test environment both and those ~30K strings somewhat identical on both the environments ?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170832/java-8s-streams-why-parallel-stream-is-slower  you may get idea about how  parallel streams works.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko it sends a string (length=20 apps) to azure service bus topic

Comment: @shubham yes, both were identical.

Comment: @BhanuMittal On your local environment , are you connecting to azure Service bus topic also or you are pointing to any local testable event based system. If no then it could be possible your network calls might be causing this issue for you.

Comment: How is the configuration of test environment compared to local setup like resources(CPU, RAM) ? Is there any resource intensive service running on the same instance of test environment along with your code ? I assume you ran the same parallel stream code on both the machines.